# Outlook Public Contacts

Tags: outlook-2007

I have been working on how to share contacts from user to user.  I know how to use the Share my contacts folder option, but I would like a general contacts file that I can house on a network drive that everyone can access and does not need to be invited to view.  Is this possible or a pipe dream?  Thanks in advance for your guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links are frowned upon but the answer is a Google search and cannot be further improved. See these links.

http://www.fatcow.com/knowledgebase/read_article.bml?kbid=3465

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/create-and-share-a-public-folder-HA010148803.aspx

http://www.msoutlook.info/question/292